# Cast Annotation to another type in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a web library and creating some annotations - @Get, @Put, @Post, @Delete, etc. All of them have the same properties, so is it possible to cast all of them to some "super" annotation to make working with them easier? Here's what my code looks like now:

```
public void createGetRoute(Get get) {
  this.path = get.path()
  this.method = "GET"
}

public void createPutRoute(Put put) {
  this.path = put.path()
  this.method = "PUT"
}

// ... And so on
```

What I would like to do is:

```
public void createRoute(Route route) {
  this.path = route.path()
  this.method = route.method()
}
```

Where `Route` is a "super class" of all the other annotations. I know we can't extend `@interfaces`, but is there another way I could make my code more DRY?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to gain here?  Are you trying to adhere to the DRY principle, or do you have duplicated *logic* in your annotation?  (I picked my words carefully there since annotations contain no logic.)

Comment: And you know, there are frameworks that have all these HTTP primitives?

Comment: @Makoto I'm trying to adhere to the DRY principle since a change in one annotation's properties will result in a big ripple effect throughout the code base.

Comment: @GhostCat Somebody had to write those frameworks. Somebody will have to write the next generation of frameworks. Frameworks don't just appear from the ether. We shouldn't be discouraging people from trying to write things just because somebody else already did.

Comment: @mypetlion We should encourage people to make informed decisions. If you have a clear goal implementing a framework is perfectly fine. If you only do it because you don't know better options, then you are possibly wasting your time. And honestly; when that single comment of mine discourages someone so much that he stops what he is doing ... then I seriously doubt that this person would get much further anyhow. Writing a reasonable framework is something that leads to all kinds of frustration you need to cope with.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Framework leveraged a common request annotation [known as `@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html), which accepts a method type and a few other parameters as necessary.

In *newer* versions of the framework, convenience annotations such as `@GetMapping` exist which apply the same `@RequestMapping` annotation with sensible defaults.

It'd be best for you to start with the most generic route annotation you can come up with, and *only* when there's more convenience in decanting these out into smaller approaches should you consider it.

Comment: TBH I started out this way, but as I used the library more and more, I found I wanted shortcuts. I used snippets to ease some of the burden, but verb-specific annotations is seeming to be the ideal. 

I looked at how Spring did things and it looks like they more or less duplicate the properties across each annotation. If this seems to be the only way, I guess I'll have to be careful with my refactoring (if any).

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at how a couple other frameworks do it, I decided to adopt a similar pattern. I started with a general `@Route` class:

```
public @interface Route {
  String[] value() default {"/"};
  String[] pattern() default {};
  String[] consumes() default {};
  String[] produces() default {};
  HttpMethod method() default HttpMethod.GET;
  boolean blocking() default false;
  int order() default 0;
}
```

And basically copy/pasted it for classes representing each HTTP method - GET, POST, PUT, etc.

Then I used a bit of reflection to determine which HTTP method I should assign to my routes when building my routing table:

```
RouteProperties fromAnnotation(Annotation annotation) {
    Class<? extends Annotation> type = annotation.annotationType();
    HttpMethod method;
    switch (type.getSimpleName()) {
      case "Get":
        method = GET;
        break;
      case "Post":
        method = POST;
        break;
      case "Put":
        method = PUT;
        break;
      //...
      case "Route":
        method = invoke("method", annotation, HttpMethod.class);
        break;
      default:
          method = GET;
    }
    this.method = method;
```

THe `invoke()` method you see above is how I get the values for each of the properties I'm interested in. It basically looks like this:

```
private <T> T invoke(String methodName, Object instance, Class<T> returnType) {
    T result;
    try {
      result = (T) instance.getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke(instance);
    } // Catch block
    return result;
  }
```

Aside from the copying/pasting of all the properites of the Route class across several files, this approach has significantly cut down on the amount of code I had before and is way more maintainable.

Thanks for the help, everyone!